# What is the adjective for "problem solving"?

Tags: adjectives, adjective-phrases

In [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/49388/how-should-the-drawings-be-in-cover-letter), I want to say about the drawing which is less *artistic* and more *problem solving*. But *problem solving* is not adjective, as contrast to *artistic*.

Is there an adjective for *problem solving*?

Comment: What makes you think it's not an adjective?

Comment: First thought: "V-ing" is an action, right? Second thought: ahhhhhh, I see what you mean. Make it an answer and I'll accept yours.

Comment: We say "The raptors show problem-solving intelligence."

Comment: @TRomano should I change my question to asking the *adjective form* for *problem solving*?

Comment: @TRomano But it appears that OP wants a term which can be employed predicatively. And it's not clear whether what's meant is "concerned with solving problems" or "{capable of/engaged in} solving problems".

Comment: @StoneyB: in that case, artistic  not heuristic?

Comment: @TRomano I like that a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the addition of a dash, **problem-solving** can be used adjectivally before a noun. In fact, a lot of similar adjectivals can be formed with the active participle ending in -*ing*: **habit-forming**, **all-encompassing**, **ever-increasing**, etc.

English is quite flexible on the way different parts of speech can serve as adjectives. Note that when numerical expressions are used in this way, they are never plural in form. There is a strict rule in English that adjectivals may not be pluralized. That's why you see forms like **two-mile hike**, **three-minute phone call**, **twenty-year-old girl**, etc.

Comment: May I ask what your native language is?

Comment: You say: "problem-solving can be used adjectivally **before a noun**". What if there is no noun for it?

Comment: Then it's a noun (no dash): He's good at problem solving.

Comment: I mean, is "less artistic and more problem solving" grammatical correct? *Artistic* is an adj, while *problem - solving* must be a noun since there is no noun after it.

Comment: It depends on the entire sentence. If you wanted to list ARTISTIC and PROBLEM-SOLVING as attributes, you might have to give it a little turn: He would make a good curator because he is both artistic and a good problem solver." or "... is artistic and has great problem-solving skills."